# Is XML data type proper for large tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-performance

I want to Query over 14,000,000 documents stored as XML field in SQL Server.

I've generated 1,000,000 rows in data base to test now, but simple select with no where condition takes about 3 minutes. I also applied XML Indexing but it's still not acceptable in performance. Similar scenario takes 19 Sec for similar table which have all fields as typed.

Here is my typed table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fields] (
[Id]          BIGINT     IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Title]       NCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
[Duration]    INT        NOT NULL,
[Cost]        MONEY      NOT NULL,
[Consignee]   BIGINT     NOT NULL,
[Date]        DATETIME   NOT NULL,
[TariffId]    BIGINT     NOT NULL,
[InvoiceType] NCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
[IsPayed]     BIT        NOT NULL
);
```

and this one is the one XML sample:

```
<Invoice>
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Title>title</Title>
  <Duration>726643700</Duration>
  <Cost>312118909727165.6133</Cost>
  <Consignee>3120910928797722624</Consignee>
  <Date>4543-07-16T01:40:29.623</Date>
  <TariffId>3120910928797722624</TariffId>
  <InvoiceType>InvoiceType</InvoiceType>
  <IsPayed>1</IsPayed>
</Invoice>
```

These are indexes I applied:

```
CREATE XML INDEX idx_xCol_Path on [dbo].[XML] (InvoiceItem)
   USING XML INDEX idx_xCol FOR PATH

CREATE XML INDEX idx_xCol_Value on [dbo].[XML] (InvoiceItem)
   USING XML INDEX idx_xCol FOR VALUE
```

Comment: A `SELECT *` takes 3 minutes? That doesn't seem that bad to me. I can't imagine your typical runtime queries will be `SELECT *` with no `WHERE` clause. XML indexing won't help such a query, either - it will only help if you are looking for XML docs that contain certain attributes / values. Can you show the table structures you're comparing (the table with XML column(s), and the "similar table which have all fields as typed")?

Comment: Could you please post your schema, the DDL for the tables and indexes, and the query you are running?

Comment: @Quassnoi and AaronBertrand: Sorry for delay.

Comment: Ok, I thought you were storing XML documents *and* other data. You are simply storing data as XML. Why? This isn't really what the XML type was for. Sure it makes it easy for applications that would otherwise need to serialize-deserialize etc., but this is not the way to build a decent-performing database application. Your first table seems much more optimal to me than an all-in-one single-XML column table.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: Wait a second! please read the source of my problem first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148000/using-xml-field-vs-creating-a-table-for-unstable-organization

Comment: @Reza: what query are you running?

Comment: I think there are other solutions presented to you in the other question than "Ok, guess I need to use XML for this."

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Yes, but other solutions were not completely match my requirements and he mentioned too. I've choose the first option.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Right now I'm just testing the performance of this data type. in fact, I should setup reports over this column later, and I'm concern about the performance of my reports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My vary tests made my decision change. Xml is great for about 1-2 million records. In my case, the application life time should be more that 3 years with document production velocity.
So I tried to use tables instead of xml fields. Other possible solution could be a single record, but there was xml document size limit. As I monitor the performance vs record numbers, I found out it dives after a million records. Also, Index files on SQL grow up was not acceptable with this scale.

Answer (score 1):

Big NO. Avoid XML for tables with many records, since the record definition tends to be repeated over and over again. XML is suitable for documents where the amount of mark-up is smaller in relation to data. If you want human a readable table, use csv or a similar format.