# Which Document Oriented Database with better Reporting Performance than Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, database, nosql, reporting, ravendb

I'm looking for a document oriented database to store over millions of invoices with fast reporting speed.

I find some options such as MongoDB, Ravendb, Couchdb but I don't know the risk of performance failure vs. Sql Server Xml type column.

The source of this question is [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133395/using-xml-field-vs-creating-a-table-for-unstable-organization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reza,
RavenDB seems like a good match here. It all depends on what you are actually calling "reporting".
Doing things like "how many invoices are there for last month" is easy in RavenDB.
As is doing things like "how much money does Northwind owe us?"

We don't recommend RavenDB for reporting for the specific case where you have dynamic reporting needs such as the need to do on the fly aggregation.

What is it that you are actually trying to *do* with regards to reporting?

That aside, invoices is a nice place where RavenDB truly shines, especially given the other parameters of this question with the dynamic nature of the invoices.

Comment: Ayende, Reporting over invoices is about how much and how the organization reach to income. It may deal with queries over some fields, for instance how much money is payed by one special customer or category of customers this year. That's the summary of all kind of payments. How much benefit is for one specific product category. Who by what more with which payment options? Another concern is validations.

Answer (score 3):

Fast reporting is something that you *want* to do in sql server. I'm not aware of a good NoSQL solution for this scenario.

RavenDB has the index replication bundle that enables you to replicate an index to a sql table, so that you can do some advanced reports on them.

Comment: What do you think about [this](http://ayende.com/blog/136197/when-should-you-not-use-ravendb)? **One case that we don’t recommend using RavenDB for is reporting, though.**

Comment: Daniel, I wouldn't jump to say that his reporting scenarios can't easily be handled by RavenDB. The one scenario that is hard in RavenDB is dynamic group by, and those are actually rare.

Answer (score 1):

> but I don't know the risk of performance failure vs. Sql Server Xml type column.

Epic fail already here. Invoices are relational data in most cases (in all you need) so address links, line items, numbers and prices are in tables, not XML data type. This is the "ok, so - you planned to wkr at McDonalds, not in our team?" level design decision.

What line items and invoices may have is additional data in XML (like timesheets etc.) but if you run accounting, you dont run it as documents.

Comment: Ok, maybe it's important to know why I was thinking to Document-Oriented Database. Please take a look at the [reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148000/using-xml-field-vs-creating-a-table-for-unstable-organization).

Comment: "The Data Model Resource Book", Volume 1. Had a full data model for invoicing and accounting. There is no "unstable organization" in a regulated and well unerstood area like accounting. There is only a developer not knowing standard models.

Comment: That's very good point. But in many cases, every thing doesn't goes that way you or regulations expect.

Comment: ;) I still have to find one organization that got away doing accounting "not the way the law says" and one case where the model given in the book was not valid. Most "I need to be smarter" in 20 years IT turned out to be "I dontreally know what is out therea nd how to design properly". invoice management / accounting is one of those areas.

Comment: TomTom, invoices are relation data? Absolutely not! Inovices are denormalized snapshots of relational data, something that works just perfectly in document databases. You don't want the address to change, you don't want prices or even product titles to change. Invoices are completely non-relational.

Comment: Yes, what a poor answer.